# CherryPy debug is not working but normal is

Tags: python, cherrypy, vscode-devcontainer

I'm developping some small web application with CherryPY. I'm using a devcontainer and vscode. Everythong is running well except when I'm trying to run it in a debug mode. It raises an error saying `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cherrypy'`

but when I start `python myfile.py` this is working I don't understand the difference.

Here is my devcontainer dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.11.3-bullseye

# run this before copying requirements for cache efficiency
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY .devcontainer/requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```